# Two list count specific elements and aggregate on spefic rule

Tags: python, list

Hi I stumble upon some problem that I cannot come up with solution. 
**I have two lists** `list1=[2,5,7]`and `list2=[4,6,9]` and as well as the following variables

```
counter1=[], counter2=[] # Counter of each list,
sum1=[], sum2=[] # Sum of highest elements
```

I would like to pick the **first three highest element** from the lists in this case **9, 7, 6 (9,7 from list1 and 6 from list2)**. As consequence I need to map from which list each numbers belong **e.g. 9,7 to list1** therefore I need to increment counter variables in the way to counts for each of the list how many of **top 3 elements** contains in our toy example **counter1=[2]** and **counter2=[1]**.

Moreover I need to increment as well sum1 in way to take sum for each of **top3** from each list **e.g. sum1=[9+6=15]** and **sum2=[7]**.

Would you like to help to figure out how to solve this challenge? Please be welcome to suggest any kind of solution to problem. Last but not least is it possible to suggest how we can build for different scenario e.g. instead of **top3** element let say **top5** and how we can wrap this into function.

**N.B.** I cannot have same number in both lists.

Comment: SO is no "gimme problem, we solve for you" kind of forum. You are supposed to code your solution, and we might be able to help you fix it, if you get errors. Where is your solution to this problem of yours? Simplest solution: sort both lists, check the largest of each, take it , increment counter until you got what you need. very straightforward.

Comment: I do not know how to increment counter and sum together. I do not have solution so far.

Comment: also your problem is underspecified - what do you do if you got the same number in both lists, which do you take?

Comment: I cannot have the same number in the list.

Comment: Doesn't my solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible solutions. In my opininion this is the easiest:

```
import heapq

list1 = [2,5,7]
list2=[4,6,9]

counter1=0
counter2=0

sum1=0
sum2=0

full_list = list1 + list2
three_largest = heapq.nlargest(3,full_list)

for n in three_largest:
    if n in list1:
        list1.remove(n)
        counter1+=1
        sum1+=n
    else:
        list2.remove(n)
        counter2+=1
        sum2+=n

print(counter1)
print(counter2)
print(sum1)
print(sum2)
```

Note that you made a mistake in your example for the values you provide. 9 is in list2

**EDIT**

Here is an example that deals with **N** highest numbers in **M** lists:

```
import heapq
from typing import List

list_of_lists = [[1,2,3,4],[4,3,7,12],[8,8,10,1]]



def quick_metric(n_highest,lists:List[List[int]]):
    counters = [0 for i in range(len(lists))]
    sums = [0 for i in range(len(lists))]
    flat_list = [item for sublist in lists for item in sublist]
    highest = heapq.nlargest(n_highest, flat_list)

    for n in highest:
        for x_list in lists:
            if n in x_list:
                x_list.remove(n)
                counters[lists.index(x_list)]+=1
                sums[lists.index(x_list)]+=n
                break

    print(counters)
    print(sums)
    print(highest)


quick_metric(3,list_of_lists)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 12, 18]
[12, 10, 8]
```

Comment: Take lists of [2,4,6,8] and [8,8,8] as list2 and your counter produces wrong results. you can only take 8 once from list1 - then you would need the ones from list2 - which your code does not do. Itds probably better to stuff both lists into Counter(), build a set from the numbers available in each counter() and decrese the counters while taking numbers from it ...

Comment: That is right, I corrected the mistake

Comment: @mrangry777. Thank you for your response and solution. I have two question why for counter you use integer and I cannot understand what is doing **split_point**?

Comment: split_point is unnecessary I was thinking of a different solution I will remove it. You can use for counter whatever you like. However, it is a counter so it should count so why not int ?

Comment: @mrangry777 I cannot express my gratitude. Thank you so much for help. I really appreaciate your second solution. It's rocks. Again thank you for time and help I wish you all good things to you :)